# Substitute for vim replace in Sublime

Tags: vim, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I'm looking for a replacement for vim's "replace with character" command--specifically, I want to be able to select some text and replace each character with some character that I type (difficulty: No "vintage" mode)

Example:

Starting with

`I am some text with an arbitrary number: 12358998281`

I want an easy way to select `12358998281` and turn it into `99999999999`, to make the result

`I am some text with an arbitrary number: 99999999999`

(in vim, this would be done by moving the cursor to the beginning of `12358998281`, selecting with `ve`, then pressing `r9`)

I can do this by selecting the text, bringing up the "find" dialog, making sure "in selection" and "by regex" are enabled, searching for ., then typing my character into the resulting multiselect. This is incredibly laborious, however, and it prevents me from doing this process on a multiselect (for example, if `12358998281` exists in multiple parts of the file, I might want to quickly replace all instances of it with `99999999999`, rather than performing the process above, getting the substitution, copying it to the clipboard, and then replacing with that).

Does Sublime have a command that acts like vim's "replace" that I can bind to something, or do I have to write a macro to get what I need? Or, am I approaching this from entirely the wrong direction?

A more generalized way of thinking of this is "how can I break a select into a multiselect on all characters", if that helps.

Comment: Are you using Sublime's vi mode?

Comment: No--that's what I'm referring to with the statement, 'difficulty: No "vintage" mode' (vintage mode is the name for vi-mode)

Comment: Ah yes, I guess I didn't see that :)

Comment: IMO, vim tag doesn't make much sense... it pulls me here, but it is pure sublime question...

Comment: Happy to take it off, but my rationale was that this is a vim-to-sublime question (i.e., probably not something you'd even bother to think about unless you'd used vim at some point)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this with a simple (if inelegant) plugin:

```
import sublime_plugin
import sublime


class MultiSelectWithinSelectedCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        selection = self.view.sel()
        new_regions = []

        for selected_region in selection:
            if selected_region.empty():
                selection.add(self.view.word(selected_region))

        for selected_region in selection:
            if selected_region.a > selected_region.b:
                region_begin = selected_region.b

            else:
                region_begin = selected_region.a

            for pos in range(selected_region.size()):
                subregion_begin = region_begin + pos
                subregion_end = subregion_begin + 1
                new_regions.append(sublime.Region(subregion_begin, subregion_end))

        selection.clear()
        selection.add_all(new_regions)
```

Once I've stuck this in my plugins directory, I would bind a command in the keymap file like usual:

```
{ "keys": ["alt+f"], "command": "multi_select_within_selected" }
```

(with alt+f chosen arbitrarily), and lo, multi-select on all selected characters with a keypress (after which, I can press my replacement character).

Comment: Well If it does what you were looking for and I'm pretty sure I haven't seen anything that replaces all characters in selection with one character, I think you should release it in https://sublime.wbond.net/ for other people to enjoy. But CTRL+B is build shortcut. At least on windows, so here it should be something different. ALT+F is free by default I think.

Comment: Yeah, ctrl+b is that, I was just putting in whatever popped into my head (I had it bound to a ctrl+k combination), but your alt+f choice is much better. I'll probably stick it in Package Control once I have a version that isn't too terrible. Thanks for all the input.

Answer (score 0):

By using this package https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/RegReplace you can create regex patterns and bind them to shortcuts.

Also if there are multiple occurrences of one word, you can put cursor on whatever part of the word and press CTRL+D multiple times. One CTRL+D press will select the word under the cursor, every other press will select next occurrence of the word.

You could also use https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Expand%20Selection%20to%20Whitespace to expand the selection to whitespace if your word contain some random characters, and then press CTDL+D to select next occurrences of the word.

Edit: With the package regex shortcuts indeed you have to create regexes before binding them. But the CTRL+D does work without it.
I don't see a problem with using "Expand selection to whitespace" and than doing the CTRL+D as I wrote in the answer.

I've checked the usage of visual as you wrote in the question and this solution seems much faster to do. You don't have to place cursor in the beggining of the word as It can be whereever in the word and no find/replace is needed, since you'll multiselect all occurrences by holding CTRL+D for a sec and You'll be free to edit it.

You can also use https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Expand%20Selection%20to%20Quotes to select text inside quote and combine it with CTRL+D if standard CTRL+D doesn't work with some text, or if select to whitespace selects too much text.

Comment: This seems to require that the replacement be defined beforehand, which would nullify any gains from the shortcut for this type of usage. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Check edited answer since It was too long for comment.

Comment: I may be obtuse, but I'm not seeing how that gets around the problem that the replacement text still has to be predefined. In my example, that's the "9"--with RegReplace, I would have to edit the command to have "9" as its replacement before I could actually use it.

In any case, I was able to solve it by puttering around in Sublime's API docs

Comment: I see that I was misunderstood. RegReplace was just one package which requires you to do regexes before using them and an example. But what you were looking for, at least looking at selecting word and it occurrences and replacing it, can be achieved by shortcuts only without any package. There's no need to specify any regexes to replace one specified existing word. Example http://youtu.be/C8IaGqyrTaQ. Sorry for the music, didn't notice it was recording system sounds.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. I see where the misunderstanding is, the video helps. What I'm looking for is specifically functionality to replace all the selected text's characters with one repeated character, without having to type that character whatever number of times the text is (because length may vary over my multi-select, for example, or because it's 40 characters and I don't want to worry about/check whether I've counted to 40 correctly). If you try the "r" command in "vintage mode", you'll see what I mean. Thanks for the research, though, I appreciate it.